# Error upon testing OneToMany relationship to Postman with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "user")
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    // Hibernate requires a no-arg constructor
    public User() {

    }
    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

**UserProfile**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profiles")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
   private String phoneNumber;
    private String gender;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public UserProfile() {

    }
    public UserProfile(String phoneNumber, String  gender,
                       String address1, String address2, String street, String city,
                       String state, String country, String zipCode) {

        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.gender = gender;

        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

**My Service**

```
@Component
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(String  firstName, String  lastName, String email, String password){
        User user=new User(firstName,lastName,email,password);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> savedataBase(User user){
        userRepo.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( userRepo.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class UserPServer {
    @Autowired
    UserProfileRepo userProfileRepo;
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserProfile>> save(UserProfile userProfile){
        userProfileRepo.save(userProfile);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( userProfileRepo.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/create/{firsName}/{lastName}/{email}/{password}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> create(@PathVariable("firsName") String firstName,
                                       @PathVariable("lastName") String  lastName,
                                       @PathVariable("email") String email,
                                       @PathVariable("password") String password){
        return userService.createUser(firstName,lastName,email,password);
    }
    @PostMapping("/usersave")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> saveDateBase(@RequestBody User users){
        return  userService.savedataBase(users);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/userprofile")
public class UserPConroller {
    @Autowired
   UserPServer userPServer;
    @PostMapping("/userpsave")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserProfile>> savep(UserProfile userProfile){
        return  userPServer.save(userProfile);
    }
}
```

**UserProfile classes like above**

**I get error like this**:

> *Column 'user_id' cannot be null
>   2019-12-26 11:27:35.618 ERROR 6540 --- [nio-8883-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

Comment: I'm just starting to learn,Best Regards

Comment: could you please add UserProfile  class

Answer (score 0):

edit your **application.properties** file like this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 0):

- Once you decided who is the "parent" in this relationship you should save the child first with its repository.

Lets assume it is the `User`.

You would do something like this in your controller

```
UserProfile newUser = user.getUserProfile();
userProfileRepository.save(newUser);
userRepository.save(user);
```

This guarantee garantee that the relation is successful.